# Dual boot Linux Mint in a GPT style hard drive along with Windows 8

Tags: linux-mint, uefi, gpt

I have a Sony VAIO e series laptop which came with Windows 8. I wish to install Linux Mint as additional operating system. Only at the time of installation I could find that my HDD is of GPT partition style and my bios was also set in UEFI mode.

After setting the bios to legacy mode the HDD became unbootable giving a error that "operating system not found" every time I try to turn on my laptop. Since MBR style HDD is required for legacy mode and booting multiple operating systems, I tried many software which converts GPT to MBR HDD but there was no use in it.

How can I install Linux Mint while keeping the Windows 8 untouched?

Note: my motherboard can be set to UEFI and legacy boot mode. I want to boot both Windows 8 and Linux. It will be good if you suggest me a solution without formatting my HDD.